# Android AsyncTask exception and onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have two AsyncTask classes.
First:

```
private class NotationChanger extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        synchronized(mutex) {
            try {
                this.infixToPostNotation();
            } catch(ParseErrorException e) {
                Log.i("Parse Error Exception", e.getMessage());
                changedNotationError = true;
            }
            finally {
                mutex.notify();                         //Calculator waits while notation is being changed
            }                                           //So we should wake it                      
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        changedNotation = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        changedNotation = true;
    } 

    ...
}
```

Second:

```
private class Calculator extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        synchronized(mutex) {
            while(!changedNotation) {
                try {
                    mutex.wait();
                }   catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i("Calculation", "waked");

        if(!changedNotationError) {
            try {
                this.calculatePoints();
            } catch (CalculateException e) {
                Log.i("Calculate exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            changedNotationError = false;
        }

        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see when NotationChanger has done his work it wakes Calculator class. It works fine while there is no an exception. When I get a ParseErrorException in NotationChanger class method onPostExecute isn't called.

If I move

```
changedNotation = true;
```

from onPostExecute function to finally block it works well every time. Does it mean that exception in doInBackground breaks calling of onPostExecute method or I don't understand anything?

Comment: Can you post your error log ? Will help us, I understand that you have already explained everything but sometimes we can see something different :)

Comment: since honeycomb, there is only 1 thread for asynctasks. which means they run sequentially. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: There are no errors. Just something like  '08-21 16:57:07.685: I/Parse Error Exception(3796): 'x' is missed' (that is my custom exception) and no 'Waked' message after.

Comment: Also I count threads and display their number. When 'changedNotation = true' placed in onPostExecute than after exception their number doesn't decrease.

Answer (score 0):

If Calculator run first, and waiting in doInBackground().
I think that your NotationChanger can not enter doInBackground().
In my experience, all AsyncTask use only one thread to work.